# Excel, Conditional formatting rows based on time values

Tags: excel, function, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I cant figure out a formula for conditional formatting to highlight a row (not just a cell) based on a cells value being less then a specific time.

The less then time is "18:00"

I have 4 columns and 50 rows and the time data is in column D2 (D2 to D51)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply conditional formatting to the range `A2:D51` and use the following formula as a condition:
`=$D2<TIME(18,0,0)`

Comment: Also, the "Applied To" range should just be rows, i.e. `2:51`. If OP uses say `$D2:$D51`, then it'll only highlight the cell.  It's not mentioned, but OP may have the formula right, but can't figure out how to get it to do *rows* instead of *cells*, so I just thought to mention it.

Comment: @BruceWayne I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that the OP wanted to highlight only the 4 columns with data in them (assumed to be `A:D`). If the entire row is to be highlighted, you are correct.

Comment: Ah - I can see that too. Right now it's a little unclear, but good call.